# Binding a DependancyProperty from an Application resource to a Control DependancyProperty (that is using the resource)

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, data-binding, custom-controls

I am trying to build a custom class inherited from the Image control and I am having some trouble with binding.

I am using DrawingImage in my resources (that's what is supplied for the vector image)

so in my App.xaml resources I have a few DrawingImages, example of one:

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="Shutdown">
            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <DrawingGroup.Children>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{x:Null}">
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                             Here-->    <Pen Brush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:IconImage}}, Path=Colour, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Thickness="2" />
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                        <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="M8.332,4.941C5.759,6.271 4,8.956 4,12.052 4,16.47 7.582,20.052 12,20.052 16.418,20.052 20,16.47 20,12.052 20,8.911 18.19,6.193 15.555,4.884" />
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                </GeometryDrawing>
                       Here-->  <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:IconImage}}, Path=Colour, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Pen="{x:Null}">
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                        <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Rect="11,2,2,10" />
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                </GeometryDrawing>
                            </DrawingGroup.Children>
                            <DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,24,24" />
                            </DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingGroup.Children>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
        </DrawingImage>
```

and I have built my custom class as follows:

```
 public class IconImage : Image
{
    public enum Icons
    {
        None,
        Shutdown,
        Minimize
    }

    private Icons _icon;
    public Icons Icon
    {
        get { return _icon; }
        set
        {
            _icon = value;
            if (value == Icons.None)
            {
                Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
            else
            {
                Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                this.SetResourceReference(Image.SourceProperty, value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColourProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Colour", typeof(Brush), typeof(IconImage), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));

    public Brush Colour
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ColourProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColourProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Usasge:

```
<local:IconImage Icon="Shutdown" Colour="CornflowerBlue" />
```

Problem is my Brush bindings in the DrawingImages wont bind to my Colour DependancyProperty in the custom class and I have no idea how to accomplish this, or, if it is even possible. If I hard code the brushes it works perfectly (Obviously). I just need to be able to change the colour of them from the control at design time, or at anytime in code behind.

Thanks in advance!

-Sean-

Comment: Where was the `DrawingImage` used? Sure having `AncestorType` of `local:IconImage` for the `DrawingImage`?

Comment: It is used when the Icon property is set: this.SetResourceReference(Image.SourceProperty, value.ToString()); that sets it to the DynamicReference of "Shutdown" in this case.

Comment: Could you please show the code which uses the resource of `x:Key="Shutdown"`?

Comment: In the IconImage class: when the 'Icon' property is set it sets the Source of the image to reference the x:Key="Shutdown" resource because I am setting the Icon to "Shutdown". Its an Enum, I just use the ToString() because my Enum values exactly match the x:Key names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it work like this. First mark resource as non-shared, because your want to make your `DrawingImage` to change appearance based on which `IconImage` it is part of, which does not make much sense for a shared resource (shared in this case means like singleton - only one global instance):

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="Shutdown" x:Shared="False">
    <!-- the rest -->
</DrawingImage>
```

Then instead of using `SetResourceReference` do it like this:

```
var resource = FindResource(value.ToString());
// alternative
// var resource = Application.Current.Resources[value.ToString()];
this.Source = (ImageSource)resource;
```

This will be roughly the same as putting your `DrawingImage` xaml directly under `IconImage` like other answer suggests.

You better have more unique names for your resources by the way, to avoid accidental usage of resource with the same name down the tree (especially if you are going to use `FindResource`).

Comment: This works! Thanks! One small problem, I get nothing at design time, only shows up once I run the application.  Any suggestions for this?

Comment: As for the unique names, they will be much more unique, and there is only a handful of them. This was just for an example.

Comment: @SeanMakins well often it's quite hard to make WPF designer show what you want... In this case it finds and loads resource fine, but cannot bind to your `Colour` property for some reason. You might attach another instance of Visual Studio to debug this if you'd like. As a temporary solution - provide fallback value for your bindings like this: `<Pen Brush={Binding ...., FallbackValue={x:Static Brushes.Black}}`. Then at least you will see something in designer (though of course icon will always be black, not the color you set for it in xaml).

Answer (score -1):

```
<local:IconImage Icon="Shutdown" Colour="CornflowerBlue">
    <local:IconImage.Source>
        <DrawingImage>
            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <DrawingGroup.Children>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{x:Null}">
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                        <Pen Brush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:IconImage}}, Path=Colour, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Thickness="2" />
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                        <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="M8.332,4.941C5.759,6.271 4,8.956 4,12.052 4,16.47 7.582,20.052 12,20.052 16.418,20.052 20,16.47 20,12.052 20,8.911 18.19,6.193 15.555,4.884" />
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                </GeometryDrawing>
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:IconImage}}, Path=Colour, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Pen="{x:Null}">
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                        <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Rect="11,2,2,10" />
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                </GeometryDrawing>
                            </DrawingGroup.Children>
                            <DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,24,24" />
                            </DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingGroup.Children>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
        </DrawingImage>
    </local:IconImage.Source>
</local:IconImage>
```

Comment: I am sure this could work, but this does not allow me to set the Source dynamically, I don't want to have to specify the entire DrawingImage everytime I use this control. (It is used many many times) and sometimes it changes during run time, This is why I have the Icon property.

Comment: How about letting the `Icon` to be `DependencyProperty` and using a `Style` for the `IconImage` to get what you want?